# Finding dependencies that cause React 15.5.3 PropTypes deprecated warning

Tags: reactjs

I'm in the process of upgrading an app to the new version of React.  I have updated all of my code to use the new 'prop-types' module, however, I am still getting deprecation warnings in the browser.  I cannot figure out which of my dependencies need to be updated.

Is there a way to do this besides going one by one and updating them?